# How to give each CPU core mutable access to a portion of a Vec?

Tags: rust

I've got an embarrassingly parallel bit of graphics rendering code that I would like to run across my CPU cores.  I've coded up a test case (the function computed is nonsense) to explore how I might parallelize it.  I'd like to code this using std Rust in order to learn about using `std::thread`.  But, I don't understand how to give each thread a portion of the framebuffer.  I'll put the full testcase code below, but I'll try to break it down first.

The sequential form is super simple:

```
let mut buffer0 = vec![vec![0i32; WIDTH]; HEIGHT];
for j in 0..HEIGHT {
    for i in 0..WIDTH {
        buffer0[j][i] = compute(i as i32,j as i32);
    }
}
```

I thought that it would help to make a buffer that was the same size, but re-arranged to be 3D & indexed by core first.  This is the same computation, just a reordering of the data to show the workings.

```
let mut buffer1 = vec![vec![vec![0i32; WIDTH]; y_per_core]; num_logical_cores];
for c in 0..num_logical_cores {
    for y in 0..y_per_core {
        let j = y*num_logical_cores + c;
        if j >= HEIGHT {
            break;
        }
        for i in 0..WIDTH {
            buffer1[c][y][i] = compute(i as i32,j as i32)
        }
    }
}
```

But, when I try to put the inner part of the code in a closure & create a thread, I get errors about the buffer & lifetimes.  I basically don't understand what to do & could use some guidance.  I want `per_core_buffer` to just temporarily refer to the data in `buffer2` that belongs to that core & allow it to be written, synchronize all the threads & then read `buffer2` afterwards.  Is this possible?

```
let mut buffer2 = vec![vec![vec![0i32; WIDTH]; y_per_core]; num_logical_cores];
let mut handles = Vec::new();
for c in 0..num_logical_cores {
    let per_core_buffer = &mut buffer2[c]; // <<< lifetime error
    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        for y in 0..y_per_core {
            let j = y*num_logical_cores + c;
            if j >= HEIGHT {
                break;
            }
            for i in 0..WIDTH {
                per_core_buffer[y][i] = compute(i as i32,j as i32)
            }
        }
    });
    handles.push(handle)
}
for handle in handles {
    handle.join().unwrap();
}
```

The error is this & I don't understand:

```
error[E0597]: `buffer2` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:50:36
   |
50 |         let per_core_buffer = &mut buffer2[c]; // <<< lifetime error
   |                                    ^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
88 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

The full testcase is:

```
extern crate num_cpus;
use std::time::Instant;
use std::thread;

fn compute(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 {
    (x*y) % (x+y+10000)
}

fn main() {
    let num_logical_cores = num_cpus::get();
    const WIDTH: usize = 40000;
    const HEIGHT: usize = 10000;
    let y_per_core = HEIGHT/num_logical_cores + 1;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Serial Calculation...
    let mut buffer0 = vec![vec![0i32; WIDTH]; HEIGHT];
    let start0 = Instant::now();
    for j in 0..HEIGHT {
        for i in 0..WIDTH {
            buffer0[j][i] = compute(i as i32,j as i32);
        }
    }
    let dur0 = start0.elapsed();

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // On the way to Parallel Calculation...
    // Reorder the data buffer to be 3D with one 2D region per core.
    let mut buffer1 = vec![vec![vec![0i32; WIDTH]; y_per_core]; num_logical_cores];
    let start1 = Instant::now();
    for c in 0..num_logical_cores {
        for y in 0..y_per_core {
            let j = y*num_logical_cores + c;
            if j >= HEIGHT {
                break;
            }
            for i in 0..WIDTH {
                buffer1[c][y][i] = compute(i as i32,j as i32)
            }
        }
    }
    let dur1 = start1.elapsed();

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Actual Parallel Calculation...
    let mut buffer2 = vec![vec![vec![0i32; WIDTH]; y_per_core]; num_logical_cores];
    let mut handles = Vec::new();
    let start2 = Instant::now();
    for c in 0..num_logical_cores {
        let per_core_buffer = &mut buffer2[c]; // <<< lifetime error
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            for y in 0..y_per_core {
                let j = y*num_logical_cores + c;
                if j >= HEIGHT {
                    break;
                }
                for i in 0..WIDTH {
                    per_core_buffer[y][i] = compute(i as i32,j as i32)
                }
            }
        });
        handles.push(handle)
    }
    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
    let dur2 = start2.elapsed();

    println!("Runtime: Serial={0:.3}ms, AlmostParallel={1:.3}ms, Parallel={2:.3}ms",
             1000.*dur0.as_secs() as f64 + 1e-6*(dur0.subsec_nanos() as f64),
             1000.*dur1.as_secs() as f64 + 1e-6*(dur1.subsec_nanos() as f64),
             1000.*dur2.as_secs() as f64 + 1e-6*(dur2.subsec_nanos() as f64));

    // Sanity check
    for j in 0..HEIGHT {
        let c = j % num_logical_cores;
        let y = j / num_logical_cores;
        for i in 0..WIDTH {
            if buffer0[j][i] != buffer1[c][y][i] {
                println!("wtf1? {0} {1} {2} {3}",i,j,buffer0[j][i],buffer1[c][y][i])
            }
            if buffer0[j][i] != buffer2[c][y][i] {
                println!("wtf2? {0} {1} {2} {3}",i,j,buffer0[j][i],buffer2[c][y][i])
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to expand on why it is not also answered by the answers in [How do I pass disjoint slices from a vector to different threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33818141/155423) or [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32750829/155423). This is a pretty common question.

Comment: Please also include [Processing vec in parallel: how to do safely, or without using unstable features?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31644152/155423); [How do I run parallel threads of computation on a partitioned array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28599334/155423); [Using crossbeam scoped threads with vector chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34665293/155423); [Concurrent access to vector from multiple threads using a mutex lock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43428512/155423); and [Consume non-overlapping vector chunks, and combine results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31121250/155423).

Comment: I find it very useful to perform a search using Google when asking a question like this. All of the above existing questions were found with the search query `site:stackoverflow.com rust split vec thread`. And to be clear, it's fine to ask your question. If it's answered by an answer in one of the above links, we can mark it as such. Right now, it appears as if you didn't do research before asking; explaining how it's different shows you've done due diligence, read existing answers (that's why they are there!), thought about it, and come to the conclusion that your question is truly unique.

Comment: I did do a google search and did find some of these.  I am looking through all of these and will have to take some time to see if they answer my question as posed.

Comment: The first two suggestions require crossbeam & scoped_threadpool -- is this such a complicated question that it requires external crates?  The next suggests simple_parallel, the next wants to send/receive the data (unecessary overhead). The https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428512/concurrent-access-to-vector-from-multiple-threads-using-a-mutex-lock seems like it might apply.  I will look at this one...

Comment: *is this such a complicated question that it requires external crates* — Rust doesn't even have random number generation in the standard library. Due to the wonderful Cargo ecosystem, the barrier for what belongs in the standard library is drastically different in Rust compared to other languages and it's something I highly encourage people to openly embrace. Otherwise, you are going to be rewriting a lot of code. And yes, sharing data across threads in a performant, safe manner is non-trivial. There was an implementation in the standard library that was *wrong*, originally, and thus removed.

Comment: [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Shepmaster for the pointers and clarification that this is not an easy problem for Rust, and that I needed to consider crates to find a reasonable solution.  I'm only just starting out in Rust, so this really wasn't clear to me.

I liked the ability to control the number of threads that [scoped_threadpool](https://crates.io/crates/scoped_threadpool) gives, so I went with that. Translating my code from above directly, I tried to use the 4D buffer with core as the most-significant-index and that ran into troubles because that 3D vector does not implement the `Copy` trait.  The fact that it implements `Copy` makes me concerned about performance, but I went back to the original problem and implemented it more directly & found a reasonable speedup by making each row a thread.  Copying each row will not be a large memory overhead.

The code that works for me is:

```
let mut buffer2 = vec![vec![0i32; WIDTH]; HEIGHT];
let mut pool = Pool::new(num_logical_cores as u32);
pool.scoped(|scope| {
    let mut y = 0;
    for e in &mut buffer2 {
        scope.execute(move || {
            for x in 0..WIDTH {
                (*e)[x] = compute(x as i32,y as i32);
            }
        });
        y += 1;
    }
});
```

On a 6 core, 12 thread i7-8700K for 400000x4000 testcase this runs in 3.2 seconds serially & 481ms in parallel--a reasonable speedup.

EDIT: I continued to think about this issue and got a suggestion from Rustlang on twitter that I should consider [rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon).  I converted my code to [rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon) and got similar speedup with the following code.

```
let mut buffer2 = vec![vec![0i32; WIDTH]; HEIGHT];
buffer2
    .par_iter_mut()
    .enumerate()
    .map(|(y,e): (usize, &mut Vec<i32>)| {
        for x in 0..WIDTH {
            (*e)[x] = compute(x as i32,y as i32);
        }
    })
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```